# Don't let the user leave the page?

Tags: javascript, html, web

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   return "Dont leave me";
   return;
};
```

So thats my HTML-Code(JavaScript) so far and its working.

Now there will be a pop up if you try to leave.

Is there any oppertunity to loop the user in this pop-Up when he clicks on leaving?

Comment: No, browsers will protect users against that.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do this except for nefarious purposes.

Comment: Do you want to harm someone? :)

Comment: no worries guys, i just want to use this for spoiling friends.
And im pretty sure there has to be a way, cuz i was trapped in this situation sometime ago.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to prevent users from leaving the website.